# How to remove old build plans installed by Haskell stack?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

How can I remove old build plans (GHC compiler and packages) installed by the stack tool?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would poke around ~/.stack and delete whatever files you don't want anymore:

- compiled libraries for a resolver in ~/.stack/snapshots/...
- compiler toolchains in ~/.stack/programs/...
- build plan yaml files in ~/.stack/build-plan/...